# Having problems while building or running a code using Codeblocks 13.12

Tags: code-blocks

One of my mates told me that she is having problem while trying to build or run a code in Codeblocks (version 13.12). No environment error is shown. Whenever she tries to build a code nothing happens. But when she tries to run the code there is shown that the code is not build yet. What can we do to solve this?

Comment: What kind of code? How exactly is she trying to build and run it (sequence of menu selections)? What is shown in the 'Build log' pane (copy and paste the contents into your question)?

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem. It means that either the GCC compiler is missing in your Ubuntu or you have not set the correct path name for the compiler:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install g++
```